# kept getting file.create error when trying to activate flutter screenshots

Tags: flutter, dart, debugging, imagemagick, flutter-dependencies

I am following the installation steps for screenshots using this link https://github.com/mmcc007/screenshots/blob/master/README.md

The installation steps:
macOS:
brew update && brew install imagemagick
pub global activate screenshots

I have been stucked on "pub global activate screenshots". It kept giving me errors like:

Failed to build screenshots:main:
../../.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dev/file-5.2.1/lib/src/interface/file.dart:16:16: Error: The method 'File.create' has fewer named arguments than those of overridden method 'File.create'.
Future create({bool recursive = false});

../../flutter/bin/cache/dart-sdk/lib/io/file.dart:232:16: Context: This is the overridden method ('create').
Future create({bool recursive = false, bool exclusive = false});

../../.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dev/file-5.2.1/lib/src/interface/file.dart:16:16: Error: The method 'File.create' doesn't have the named parameter 'exclusive' of overridden method 'File.create'.
Future create({bool recursive = false});

../../flutter/bin/cache/dart-sdk/lib/io/file.dart:232:16: Context: This is the overridden method ('create').
Future create({bool recursive = false, bool exclusive = false});

../../.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dev/file-5.2.1/lib/src/forwarding/forwarding_file.dart:23:8: Error: The method 'ForwardingFile.createSync' has fewer named arguments than those of overridden method 'File.createSync'.
void createSync({bool recursive = false}) =>

../../flutter/bin/cache/dart-sdk/lib/io/file.dart:248:8: Context: This is the overridden method ('createSync').
void createSync({bool recursive = false, bool exclusive = false});

../../.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dev/file-5.2.1/lib/src/forwarding/forwarding_file.dart:23:8: Error: The method 'ForwardingFile.createSync' doesn't have the named parameter 'exclusive' of overridden method 'File.createSync'.
void createSync({bool recursive = false}) =>

../../.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dev/file-5.2.1/lib/src/interface/file.dart:13:16: Context: This is the overridden method ('createSync').
abstract class File implements FileSystemEntity, io.File {

../../.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dev/file-5.2.1/lib/src/backends/memory/memory_file.dart:51:8: Error: The method 'MemoryFile.createSync' has fewer named arguments than those of overridden method 'File.createSync'.
void createSync({bool recursive = false}) {

../../flutter/bin/cache/dart-sdk/lib/io/file.dart:248:8: Context: This is the overridden method ('createSync').
void createSync({bool recursive = false, bool exclusive = false});

../../.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dev/file-5.2.1/lib/src/backends/memory/memory_file.dart:51:8: Error: The method 'MemoryFile.createSync' doesn't have the named parameter 'exclusive' of overridden method 'File.createSync'.
void createSync({bool recursive = false}) {

../../.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dev/file-5.2.1/lib/src/interface/file.dart:13:16: Context: This is the overridden method ('createSync').
abstract class File implements FileSystemEntity, io.File {

../../.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dev/platform-2.2.1/lib/src/interface/local_platform.dart:45:41: Error: Member not found: 'packageRoot'.
String get packageRoot => io.Platform.packageRoot;

Someone else have the same problem as me on stackoverflow, i have tried the solutions provided but to no avail. The following are the solutions that i have tried.

Delete pubspec.lock

> Run flutter pub get

> dart pub upgrade
>
> dart pub outdated
>
> dart pub upgrade --major-versions

> flutter pub outdated -h
>
> flutter pub upgrade

> flutter pub outdated -h
>
> flutter pub upgrade --major-versions

> flutter doctor

adding file: ^6.1.4 in my dependencies

> flutter clean
>
> flutter pub get

> flutter channel stable
>
> flutter upgrade

> flutter pub downgrade file

> flutter pub upgrade file

> brew reinstall imagemagick

This is my pub outdated:

[image]

Comment: Your version of `package:file` is outdated.  Try running `flutter pub upgrade`.

Comment: i did. They gave me this, 
"No dependencies changed.
10 packages have newer versions incompatible with dependency constraints.
Try `flutter pub outdated` for more information."

Shou.d i try to force use newer versions?

Comment: Show the result of `flutter pub outdated`.

Comment: i have added an image of my flutter pub outdated results

Comment: Did you run `flutter pub get` *after* running `flutter pub upgrade`?  If all else fails, you can run `flutter pub clean` to clear your `.pub-cache` directory.

Comment: i tried but am still getting the same error